# mysql query with group by and order

Tags: mysql

Table structure:

```
country
season
points
```

Current query:

```
SELECT SUM(points) AS total, country 
FROM table 
WHERE season >= X 
GROUP BY country 
ORDER BY total desc
```

This gives me a nice list ordered by a total points collected by a given country. BUT, if a country is tied with another country, I want to sort by their points in the latest season given, is that possible within the same query? And if so, how? (Remember its grouped at the moment)

example of rows
denmark (country), 1 (season), 10 (points)
denmark (country), 2 (season), 5 (points)
sweden(country), 1 (season), 5 (points)
sweden (country), 2 (season), 10 (points)

Comment: What does that mean "if a country is tied with another country"? And how do you know this?

Comment: I guess he means when they have the same total of points

Comment: I'd just add another clause to the order by. ORDER BY total,season DESC

Comment: yeah sorry, if they share the same total amount of points.

Comment: And if the previous season is tied, order by the one before that? This is going to be recursive, so not a very good fit for sql. Could you precalculate the rankings and store in a separate table?

Comment: Hi Troels - yeah I might have to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this'll do your trick:

```
SELECT SUM(points) AS total, country 
FROM table 
WHERE season >= X 
GROUP BY country 
ORDER BY total DESC, (SELECT t2.points FROM table t2 WHERE table.country=t2.country ORDER BY t2.season LIMIT 1) DESC
```

Comment: im thinking this is a wee bit better performance wise than the query from ypercube?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT grp.total, grp.country
FROM
        ( SELECT SUM(points) AS total, country, MAX(season) AS max_season 
          FROM table 
          WHERE season >= X 
          GROUP BY country 
        ) AS grp
    LEFT JOIN
        table AS t
            ON  t.country = grp.country
            AND t.season = LATEST_SEASON
ORDER BY 
    grp.total DESC
  , t.points DESC ;
```

Comment: thx - this helped :) Now just I just have to decide if its too heavy compared to putting in the actual place instead of getting it each time like this :)